# count total number of occurrences in parallel

Tags: c, cuda

I have a parallelized algorithm that can output a random number from 1 to 1000. 
My objective is to compute, for N executions of the algorithm, how many times each number is chosen.
So for instance, I am doing N/100 executions of the algorithm, on 100 threads, and the final result is an array of 1000 ints, which are the occurrences of each number.

Is there a way to parallelize this intelligently? For instance, if I only use one global array I will have to lock it every time I want to write in it, which will make my algorithm run almost as if there was no parallelization. On the other hand, I can't just make one array of 1000 numbers per threads, just to have them be 1% filled and merge them at the end.

Comment: This is a histogram problem, and does require some thought.  But there are many descriptions online of how to implement such a routine, and the CUDA SDK comes with some sample code for histogramming, and a paper describing the algorithm.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be histogramming.  If you want to do it quickly, use a library such as [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_histogram.html) or [Thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/histogram.cu).

For cases where there are a small number of bins, one approach is to have each thread operate on its own set of bins, for a segment of the input.  Then do a parallel reduction on each bin.  If you are clever about the storage organization of your bins, the parallel reduction amounts to summation of matrix columns:

```
                Bins:
         1     2    3    4   ...   1000
  T 1
  h 2
  r 3
  e .
  a .
  d 100
```

In the above example, each thread takes a segment of the input, and operates on one row of the partial sums matrix.

When all threads are finished with their segments, then sum the columns of the matrix, which can be done very efficiently and quickly with a simple for-loop kernel.

Comment: ok so that is basically the second idea I'm proposing right ? I that case I need 1000*100 ints per execution, don't I ?

Comment: Yes.  The result is only 1000 ints, but the partial sums matrix is 100*1000 ints (for 100 threads, and 1000 bins).  If your bin count is large (e.g. all  positive integers, for example) then this method won't work or has to be modified.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things you can do.
If you want to be as portable as possible, you could have one lock for each index.

If this is being run on a Windows system, I would suggest [InterlockedIncrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)